# Get button value without using onclick

Tags: javascript

This is my code :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("b1");
  a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    some code to access button value
  });
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="d11" />
  <button id="b1" class="b1" value="1">1</button>
</form>
```

Are there other ways to get the value of the `<button>` without clicking on it?

Comment: You don't want to use a click event handler but you have one in your code? I'm confused...

Comment: Please write an actual question and explain what you want to do rather than write code that may or may not work.

Comment: this question don't make sense, `a.value`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly written but I think you want to get the value of the button without using a click event correct? If that is the case then simply using the .value property chained to the dom selector method will work just fine without using a click event.

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="d11"/>
    <button id="b1" class="b1" value="1">1</button>
    </form>
    <script>

    var a = document.getElementById("b1").value;

    console.log(a);


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use element.value. To get a reference to an element by id:

```
var a = document.getElementById("b1").value;
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var a = document.getElementById("b1").value;
  console.log("VALUE: ", a);
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myform">
<input type="text" id="d11"/> 
<button id="b1" class="b1" value="1">1</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **five** ways I can think of :

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var val = b1.value; // This is the value!!!

output.innerHTML = val; // 1. way
alert(val); // 2. way
prompt(val); // 3. way
confirm(val); // 4. way
console.log(val); // 5. way
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="d11" />
  <button id="b1" class="b1" value="1">1</button>
  <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```